# How to use ManyToManyField for self class

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have one Model inside my models.py named **Account** 
In this case I wanna create a field in which I can choose my own Model Objects.
for example if I had 3 Accounts {Jack, Harry, Helena}
I want to choose the accounts I want between them. Actually I just want to create a **Following System**. Jack can follow Harry and Helena & also Helena can follow Jack or Harry
How can I do that guys?

**Account** class inside models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(**Account**, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost as in the title you used: use `'self'`. But there is a caveat: `ManyToManyField`s that refer to themselves are by default *symmetric*: if *A* is following *B*, then *B* is automatically following *A*. Perhaps that is not what you inteded. In that case, set [**`symmetrical=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical):

```
class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name='followers'
    )
```